# how to match soft aggregate features(eyes,nose,mouth) using some statistical method?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, face-recognition, feature-detection

I know a little bit of ML, and want to  implement a learning system by myself,but do not know how to do.Any one can give me a demo or use other method to compare faces?

Here is a related post:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079794/how-to-recognize-face-by-geometric-feature-such-as-eyes-nose-mouth.

Answer (score 0):

One can not reasonably answer this question bassed on the above information because of sheer vastness of the subject.

For the start you should know that these problems are usually solved using Machine Learning techniques like `Neural Networks`. You said you know a *bit* about ML but as IMHO you might want to read more or take an online Course on Machine learning.

There are some good Courses on Coursera.org one that I like is [Machine Learning by Andrew Ng](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml).

These Methods are also described in above mentioned course and there are some good assignments too, which will help you to get the detailled idea behind machine learning.

Comment: I found that sumsug galaxy III can classify faces whithout the ML and just with the face and the eyes feature.Are there some regular or rules according to these geometric feature above to identify the different faces?

Comment: @fengtianliang As it turns out, there are some other techniques too that do not require Machine Learning, and a quick search on scholar.google.com will give a no of techniques. But I would Machine learning approches are best suited for this problem. Also you can combine those two type of techniques to get better results. :)

Comment: Please see the link http://answers.opencv.org/question/5568/how-to-recognize-face-by-geometric-feature-such-as/that describe my approch without ML,but the result is bad.I plan to calculate the angle constructting with the interest points,and I am not sure this is usefull.Any other thought will be appreciative?